# Conditionally create CodePipeline actions based on CloudFormation conditions

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

Enable / disable sections of a CloudFormation for CodePipeline using Conditionals:

This creates a manual notification action once staging has been built and passed Runscope tests:

```
- InputArtifacts: []
      Name: !Join ["",[!Ref GitHubRepository, "-prd-approval"]]
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Approval
        Owner: AWS
        Version: '1'
        Provider: Manual
      OutputArtifacts: []
      Configuration:
        NotificationArn: !GetAtt ["SNSApprovalNotification", "Outputs.SNSTopicArn"]
        ExternalEntityLink: OutputTestUrl
      RunOrder: 3
```

How to enable/disable this like other CloudFormation resources with a Condition: .

Action steps don't recognize Condition: param

I could make 2 copies of the whole pipeline code one with and one without and then toggle which pipeline I create but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by conditionally inserting the [`AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html) Resource's [Action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codepipeline-pipeline-stages-actions.html) into the [`Actions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codepipeline-pipeline-stages.html#cfn-codepipeline-pipeline-stages-actions) list using the [`Fn::If`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) Intrinsic Function referencing your [`Conditions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) element, returning the Action when the Condition is true and [`AWS::NoValue`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue) (which removes the property, in this case removing the item from the list) when it is not true:

```
- !If
  - IsProdCondition
  - InputArtifacts: []
    Name: !Join ["",[!Ref GitHubRepository, "-prd-approval"]]
    ActionTypeId:
      Category: Approval
      Owner: AWS
      Version: '1'
      Provider: Manual
    OutputArtifacts: []
    Configuration:
      NotificationArn: !GetAtt ["SNSApprovalNotification", "Outputs.SNSTopicArn"]
      ExternalEntityLink: OutputTestUrl
    RunOrder: 3
  - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Comment: AWS support:
"This is a very interesting question, and it took me a while to think about it... Well, I need to admit that the solution from Stackoverflow  is the most convenient one. And I tested in my simulation stack, it worked perfect."

Comment: I am getting the following error Property Actions cannot be empty.